# Получить GameObject, если он не активен

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. У меня есть на одной линии машина и три триггера, идущих друг за другом. Второй и третий триггер выключены (*SetActive(false)*).
Я хочу, чтобы при достижении первого триггера он исчезал и появлялся второй и так далее.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject NextPoint;
    public GameObject LastPoint;
    public int i;
    public string Mark;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        i = 1;
        Mark = $"Point {i}";
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
        {
            if (col.tag == "Point")
                {
                    i++;
                    Mark = $"Point {i}";
                    NextPoint = GameObject.Find(Mark);
                    NextPoint.SetActive(true);
                }
        }

    }
```

Код не может получить GameObject второго и третьего триггера, т.к. они не активны. Что делать? и может вы предложите иные способы реализации?

Comment: Сделайте пустой объект родителем, и повесьте на него триггер, просто при попадании на него, показывайте ребенка родителя. Для этого есть специальный метод `GetComponentInChildren`.

Comment: @And , какую команду использовать для "показа ребенка родителя"?

Comment: Какую еще команду? Это тот-же объект, скрываете, потом просто юзаете метод, который я написал выше,

Comment: @And `GetComponentInChildren` не возвращает компоненты неактивных объектов.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, возвращает - у него есть перегрузка принимающая соответствующий bool

Comment: @M.Green действительно есть, но это энивей бредовый способ, гораздо проще сразу слинковать эти объекты на уровне сцены или при их создании, если они создаются в рантайме, имхо.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, да, согласен) просто сказал, что есть такое - для информации. А ответ по способу дал ниже)

Answer (score 1):

Способов, на самом деле, уйма.

Например, создайте новый класс, который будет выражением вашего триггера. У такого класса будет переменная, которая соответствует следующей точке и метод столкновения.

Когда этот метод срабатывает - вы выключаете объект, на котором висит этот экземпляр класса и включаете тот, на который он ссылается как на следующий. Если следующего нет - сообщаете основному игровому классу, что точки закончились и игра окончена (способов это сделать тоже уйма).

Сделав такой класс можете создать префаб точки, наклонировать, как угодно и связать их в правильной последовательности.

Можете, например, в этом классе сделать событие `OnRoadEndEvent`. Сделать общий игровой класс, в который повесить ссылку на первую точку. При старте игры пройтись через всю цепочку выключая объекты (вы же помните, что каждая точка ссылается на следующую), когда точки заканчиваются - подписываетесь на `OnRoadEndEvent` последней, и включайте первую.

Итоговый класс точки будет выглядеть как-то так

```
public class TriggerPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnRoadEndEvent = delegate { };

    public TriggerPoint NextTrigger;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        if (NextTrigger != null)
            NextTrigger.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        else OnRoadEndEvent();
    }
}
```

А общий класс как-то так

```
public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    TriggerPoint _firstPoint;

    TriggerPoint _endPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        _endPoint = _firstPoint;
        if (_endPoint!= null)
        {
            while (_endPoint.NextTrigger != null)
            {
                _endPoint = _endPoint.NextTrigger;
                _endPoint.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }

            _endPoint.OnRoadEndEvent += OnRoadEnd;
            _firstPoint.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void OnRoadEnd()
    {
        _endPoint.OnRoadEndEvent -= OnRoadEnd;
        print("Win!");
    }
}
```

Всё, можете строить дорожки какой угодно длинны и ничего не менять в коде.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, но вся моя загвоздка и заключается в том, что если вторая и третья точка SetActive(false) , то я не могу их включить, использовав SetActive(true).

Comment: я понял свою ошибку. я изначально, до запуска игры, самостоятельно отключил 2,3,++ точки (убрав галочку в инспекторе), думав, что так и надо. Это и не давало мне запускать их из кода.

Comment: @M.Green, проще просто сразу не отключать его. а при запуске сцены, записать куда-то и выключить, а потом включать, это проще и быстрее.

Comment: @And, так в моём коде именно это и происходит. Создаёте на сцене цепочку точек, каждая из которых ссылается на следующую. При запуске сцены `GameMaster` сам выключит все точки, подпишется на последнюю и включит первую.